# Javascript spacebar character

Tags: javascript

```
    function my_isalpha(param_1) {
      if (param_1.length == 1 && typeof param_1 == "string" && (param_1 >= "a" && param_1 <= "z" || param_1 >= "A" && param_1 <= "Z" )) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
};
```

```
    function my_isalpha(param_1) {
        if (param_1.length == 1 && typeof param_1 == "string" && param_1.toLowerCase <="z" && param_1.toLowerCase >="a") {
          return "1";
        } else {
          return "0";
        }
};
```

Once you execute with

```
my_isalpha(" ");
```

Why does the First code returns 0, but Second returns 1?

Comment: `toLowerCase` is a function, not a property.

Comment: Thanks a lot, adding brackets solves the problem

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling the function `param_1.toLowerCase`. You need to change to:

```js
if (param_1.length == 1 && typeof param_1 == "string" && param_1.toLowerCase() <="z" && param_1.toLowerCase() >="a") {
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if it is a character from '(a | A)' to '(z | Z)'. try this

```js
function isAlpha(character){
    if (character) {
        var regExp = new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z]$');
        return regExp.test(character);
    }
    return false;
}

console.log( isAlpha('a') )
console.log( isAlpha('B') )
console.log( isAlpha('3') )
console.log( isAlpha('aBc') )
```